# Interface Inheritance in VC++ || function calling issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am making drivers in VC++.

I have include header file which is containing my interfaces.

My question is: I have inherited two interfaces but my application didn't call both interface functions.

My implementation:

**devClass.h**

```
class Driver;
class DriverCallBacks;

class Driver
{
 public:
   virtual BOOL open(LPCSTR lpszPort, DriverCallBacks *pCallBacks)=0;
   virtual DriverCallBacks * SetCallBacks(DriverCallBacks *pCallBacks)=0;
   virtual Display()=0;
}

Class DriverCallBacks
{
public:
    virtual BOOL ProcessCommand(Driver *pDriver, LPCSTR Combo)=0;
    virtual BOOL Type(Driver *pDriver, int nCount)=0;
}
```

**DemoDriver.h**

```
#include<devClass.h>

SampleDriver: public Driver, public DriverCallBacks
{
  public:
    DriverCallBacks *m_pCallBack;
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
    virtual BOOL open(LPCSTR lpszPort, DriverCallBacks *pCallBacks);
    virtual DriverCallBacks * SetCallBacks(DriverCallBacks *pCallBacks);
    virtual Display();
    virtual BOOL ProcessCommand(Driver *pDriver, LPCSTR Combo);
    virtual BOOL Type(Driver *pDriver, int nCount);
}
```

**DemoDriver.cpp**

```
#include"DemoDriver.h"
#define WM_KEYS_PRESS(WM_USER+1)

SampleDriver TheDriver;

extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport)GetInterface(Driver **ppDriver)
{
  *ppDriver = &TheDriver;
}

SampleDriver::SampleDriver()
{
   m_pCallBack=o;
}
BOOL SampleDriver::open(LPCSTR lpszPort, DriverCallBacks *pCallBacks)
{
    m_pCallBack=*pCallBacks;
    return TRUE;
}
BOOL SampleDriver::ProcessCommand(Driver *pDriver, LPCSTR Combo)
{
    return TRUE;
}
BOOL SampleDriver::Type(Driver *pDriver, int nCount)
{
    return TRUE;
}
DriverCallBacks * SampleDriver::SetCallBacks(DriverCallBacks *pCallBacks)
{
    m_pCallback = pCallBacks;
    DriverCallbacks * pOld = m_pCallbacks;
    return pOld;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK SampleDriver::WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
{
    if(IsWindow(hWnd) && message == WM_KEYS_PRESS))
    {
        if (TheDriver.m_pCallback)
        {
            LPSTR lpszKeyCombo = (LPSTR)wParam;
            if (lpszKeyCombo && *lpszKeyCombo)
            {
                if (TheDriver.m_pCallback->ProcessCommand(&TheDriver,
                      lpszKeyCombo)== FALSE)
                {
                    //do something...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
void SampleDriver::Display()
{
 //Displey something...
}
```

`Driver` class functions are executed but `DriverCallBack` class functions are not called and not executed.

**notes:-**

1. if i call DriverCallBack class functions with `TheDriver.ProcessCommand(&TheDriver,lpszKeyCombo)` then function is called but not execute the windows command.
2. DriverCallBack functions containing windows command.

**Q:** Please advise me for where is mistake?

Comment: i have not include whole code in question this is just a snap. Functions containing windows commands, arrays, enums, etc.

Comment: Can you reduce the code eliminating any irrelevant stuff please? Provide a [MCVE] that demonstrates the behavior.

Comment: Show us `main()`, how you're calling the functions of `SampleDriver` and what are you expecting and what do you get.

Comment: Where do you use `SampleDriver` as `DriverCallBacks` ? (There is `GetInterface(Driver **ppDriver)` for the `Driver`).

Comment: [OT]: you should swap lines for `DriverCallbacks * pOld = m_pCallbacks;` to really return the old one.

Comment: The code you've provided is not the code you are actually running. It should not even compile. For example inside of `open` you set `m_pCallBack=*pCallBacks;` which should issue an compilation error.

Comment: You really *must* narrow this down to an [mcve].  There is just too much noise here to wade through.  My quess is that at some point you have the equivalent of:  `SampleDriver sd; void *pVoid = &sd; DriverCallBacks *pDcb = static_cast<DriverCallBacks *>(pVoid)` - which isn't going to work well.

Comment: when i wrote `TheDriver.m_pCallback->ProcessCommand(&TheDriver, lpszKeyCombo)` compiler skip this statement and execute next statement but when i wrote `TheDriver.ProcessCommand(&TheDriver, lpszKeyCombo)`  then compiler execute this statement. But as per require document i have implement `DriverCallBacks` class functions to perform windows commands.